# R: How to change name of table when using get()

Tags: r, function

I am trying to get a series of the sum of records grouped by two variables: column 'a' and then with the rest of the columns in my dataset.

When I run this below:

```
vars <- c(colnames(df))
vars<-vars[-1]

counting<-function(index) {
  count(df,a,get(index))
}

vars[]<-lapply(vars,FUN=counting)
```

the name for the column generated by get(index) is named "get(index)" in my list vars. How can I change this so that the column name in the output is the same as the original column name?

For example, (this dataframe is modified from a tutorial in datacamp), if I have this dataframe:

```
First.Name <- c("John", "Edgar", "Walt", "Jane")
Second.Name <- c("Doe", "Poe", "Whitman", "Austen")
Sex <- c("MALE", "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE")
writers_df <- data.frame(First.Name, Second.Name, Sex)
```

And I wanted to count how many rows have unique combinations of Sex and other variables, I would run:

```
vars <- c(colnames(writers_df))
vars<-vars[-3]
counting<-function(index) {
  count(df,Sex,get(index))
}

vars[]<-lapply(vars,FUN=counting)
```

The output of one of the tables would then look like:

```
Sex get(index) n
M   John       1
M   Edgar      1
M   Walt       1
F   Jane       1
```

How can I get the column get(index) named First.Name without manually changing it "by hand"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
counting<-function(var) {
  count(writers_df,Sex,!!rlang::sym(var))
}

> lapply(vars,counting)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     Sex First.Name     n
  <fctr>     <fctr> <int>
1 FEMALE       Jane     1
2   MALE      Edgar     1
3   MALE       John     1
4   MALE       Walt     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     Sex Second.Name     n
  <fctr>      <fctr> <int>
1 FEMALE      Austen     1
2   MALE         Doe     1
3   MALE         Poe     1
4   MALE     Whitman     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the underscore version: `count_`:

```
counting <- function(index) {
  count_(writers_df, c('Sex', index))
}

> lapply(vars,FUN=counting)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Sex    First.Name     n
  <fct>  <fct>      <int>
1 FEMALE Jane           1
2 MALE   Edgar          1
3 MALE   John           1
4 MALE   Walt           1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Sex    Second.Name     n
  <fct>  <fct>       <int>
1 FEMALE Austen          1
2 MALE   Doe             1
3 MALE   Poe             1
4 MALE   Whitman         1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Sex        n
  <fct>  <int>
1 FEMALE     1
2 MALE       3
```

Comment: @crayfishcray This answer is totally fine, just be aware that `count_` and the other underscore versions are deprecated, so they may be removed from future versions of dplyr.

Comment: @joran You're right, though that would be a shame, I think. I've always thought the underscore versions were more in keeping with the tidyverse philosophy: readable code + one function, one purpose.